# Increase flow of smoke

Tags: smoke-simulation

I have a scene with a smoke/gas domain and an inflow sphere emitting smoke inside. How can I increase the flow of generated smoke on Blender 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your inflow settings check the "initial velocity" and increase the speed:

[image]

if you have negative speed against gravity, adding noise might be a good idea:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Does that really make more smoke, or does it just make it faster ?

Comment: If it would make it just faster, the domain should be filled with the same density as without speed after a while, shouldn’t it?

Comment: Good way of seeing things. Seeing your Stackexchange score, I will consider you're right :-) However I simulated with -100m/s (I want the smoke to go down), and it doesn't give me the impression the domain really fills in faster. And I find this approach a bit artificial in the sense I have to anticipate the direction of the smoke. Some burning wood types will generate more smoke than others, but the smoke will move at the same speed. Or am I seeing it wrongly ?

Comment: well....whatever you do with Blender is artificial ;) i quickly made this test with default cube, quick smoke and a speed of 30 m/s: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iruK3.jpg

Comment: Hint: add some noise, if the speed is negative, it really looks smaller ;)

Comment: with this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ2Hp.png i got: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OyHY.png

Comment: Cool thanks ! I saw based on your comment that by increasing Normal (tried with 50) had a desired effect too